# when x'y >0 and A is positive definite matrix, x' A y >0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

when $x' y >0$ and A is a positive definite matrix, $x' A y > 0$?

Here, x and y is column vector so that $x' y$ is scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Namely, $$x=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},\quad y=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix},\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0&5\end{pmatrix}$$